# How Do I Add A Resx File "As A Link" In Multiple Projects Without Constantly Running Custom Tool Before Building Each Project?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, resx

I have a Library project in my solution that contains code in library modules that refer to a LibStrings.resx file.

I then have 3 other projects (call them A, B, and C) in the solution that add these library modules as well as the LibStrings.resx file "As A Link". Effectively, I'm sharing the library modules and the resx file across projects A, B, and C so changes to those files can be centralized in one place (e.g. the Library project).

The problem I'm running into is if I'm executing project A, I have to first "Run Custom Tool" on Project A's LibStrings.resx file to prevent it from throwing a missing manifest type of error.

Project A is now working fine but projects B and C are now broken as far as using the resx file.

The reason projects B and C break is because the "LibStrings.Designer.vb" file is also linked across the 3 projects.

I did a file compare and noticed the following line changes in "LibStrings.Designer.vb" when I run custom tool for project A:

Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("ProjectA.LibStrings", GetType(LibStrings).Assembly)

The problem is that the LibStrings.Designer.vb file in Projects B and C are also using the same code:

```
Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("ProjectA.LibStrings", GetType(LibStrings).Assembly)
```

Effectively, all 3 projects are trying to load "ProjectA.LibStrings".

Conversely, if I then "Run Custom Tool" on Project B, the line changes to:

```
Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("ProjectB.LibStrings", GetType(LibStrings).Assembly)
```

Now Project B works fine, but, of course, Projects A and C are broken.

This creates a vicious cycle of constantly having to run the custom tool every time before executing a different program.

What is the cleanest way to handle this problem?

P.S. One way of directly solving this problem is to simply copy the files into each project (instead of adding them as a link). The downside to that is every time I make a change to LibStrings.resx I have to remember to copy the new version into Projects A, B, and C which becomes more difficult to maintain.

P.P.S. When I used Visual Studio 2017 there was an extension "RunCustomToolOnBuild" that seemed to solve this problem by running the Custom Tool for a project immediately before building it. I upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 and, strangely, this extension was never updated to work with VS 2019.

I am looking forward to your insight.

Comment: You can create one more project D to your solution. Keep the original file in this project and in all projects A, B and C add this file as link. Then build all the projects

Comment: Hi Vivek. Thank you for your reply. How will adding a new project (say Project D) that contains only the resx files help? When I “Run Custom Tool” on Project A it will still update all the linked Designer files to look for the resource files in Project A’s namespace (thereby breaking project B and C). Unless I’m missing something?